# Render layout on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a lot of data to load and display from API. Right now I'm doing everything on one controller and page is loading very slow. I want to render layout of this site, and a gif showing that data is loading, and after load hide gif and show data. Is there any simple Ruby on Rails function to do this, or should I use a AJAX? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with AJAX. Rails allows you to easily render pages and create endpoints for your AJAX requests. It doesn't really make sense for Rails to provide more than this because how these capabilities are used will be specific to your application.

As you suggest, you'll want to render a light weight HTML page in rails, and then include some JavaScript to make an AJAX call to load and render the heavier weight data. Best of luck.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  For performance reasons I've sometimes historically moved AJAX stuff into a rake task, and indexed the data locally so that it can be retrieved faster.  This might not be applicable for your use case, however.